# jQuery 1.8 in IE 11 does not fire image load event on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11, image-loading, jquery-1.8

I have an .NET application which loads images dynamically. I have a loading gif shown until the image loads. Then the image is shown.

The loading gif image size is `16x11`.
The images that are loaded are all resized to `80px` width.

This code works in IE8-10 (But not in IE11):

```
$(imagesToLoadList).each(function () {

    var image = $(this);
    var realSrc = image.attr('real-src');

    var demandedImageIndex = parseInt(categoryId) + (scrollCount * 10) + index;

    image.unbind();
    image.bind('load', { ImageIndex: demandedImageIndex }, ImageLoaded);
    image.attr('src', realSrc);

    index++;
});

function ImageLoaded(event) {

    //after image loaded 
}
```

In IE 11, the image loads but it does not resize to `80px` and stays16x11. It will resize correctly when the event is fired again. (App has a slider, so load event is called every time slide is changed).

Any ideas on how to fix this?

FYI, doesn't matter if the image is cached or not. Thinking along the lines of the [IE8 bug](http://davidwalsh.name/image-load-event)

Comment: Add working code snippet on http://jsfiddle.net please.

Comment: @SergeyDenisov I am not working on this project anymore and dont have the code base available. I will post working fiddle if I ever get back to this.

Comment: Did you see my answer? Could you comment it?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it works well in IE 11 even with `jQuery 1.8.0`/`1.8.3` (now the latest stable versions are `1.11.3`/`2.1.4`. Click to preview to load full-size image — [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/8n0hq12f/2/):

```js
var $img = $('img');

$img.one('click', function() {
    $img.one('load', function() {
        this.width = 320;
        this.height = 240;
        console.log('Image loaded');
    });

    this.src = $(this).data('large-src');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://oi59.tinypic.com/nxtdsp.jpg"
     data-large-src="http://oi57.tinypic.com/fegkeb.jpg"/>
```

If you'll provide the working code snippet with the bug, maybe I could help you.